# Query on PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, adapter

Consider following scenario: You have a small MogoDB collection or a small MySQL table  (contains 1000 record for example, it may be read-only too ) that is used extensively and repeatedly in your app.

You decide to fetch all of its content to a PHP array and use the array instead of sending a lot of query to DB.

In above scenario how can we retrieve some array items in a manner similar to retrieving records of a DB table in an efficient way? A PDO adapter for array or any other similar facility ...

Comment: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792388/is-there-something-in-php-equivalent-to-linq-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is port of famous C# LINQ library for php.

It gives you flexible oo interface to querying data sources.

http://phplinq.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Simple example

```
// Create data source
$names = array("John", "Peter", "Joe", "Patrick", "Donald", "Eric"); 

$result = from('$name')->in($names)
            ->where('$name => strlen($name) < 5')
            ->select('$name');
```

Comment: http://habrastorage.org/storage2/b3c/95c/3f4/b3c95c3f427b11617bfe086504bc893b.png

Answer (score 1):

While you could use a combination of array_filter and the function niehztog proposed at php.net ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87912 ), I believe even with small amounts of data you will still find querying the db faster than trying to achieve the same with array processing.

Remember that MySQL caches query results - so you just hit memory with repeated queries and not the disk.